# Parse line by line, then word by word from a textarea in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

I'm creating a basic .fountain editor to html parser that pretty much checks for words typed in a textarea on keyup.

Line by line parsing works below, but of course users would type in " **bold** then *italic* " in a single line but I can't seem to get it to scan each word in a line.

Below is my code:

```
jQuery.fn.parseAsFountain = function( window, jQuery ){
    jQuery = $;
    var storybox = $(this).val();
    story = storybox.split('\n');


    // Process The entire box

    for( var i=0;i<story.length;i++ ){

        var line = story[i];

        SubstitutePerLine(line);


    }

    story_cleared = story.join('\n');
    story_breaks = story_cleared.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
    return story_breaks;

    function SubstitutePerLine(line){

        if( line.match(/^[*].*[*]$/) ){ 
            newval = line.slice(1, -1);

            if( newval.match(/^[*].*[*]$/) ){ 
                newval2 = newval.slice(1, -1);

                if( newval2.match(/^[*].*[*]$/) ){ 
                    newval3 = newval2.slice(1, -1);

                    if( newval3.match(/\\/) ) {
                        if(newval3.match(/\\\*/)){
                        slash_val = newval3.replace(/\\/, '');
                        story[i] = '<b><i>' + slash_val + '</i></b>';
                        }
                        else {
                        story[i] = '<b><i>' + newval3 + '</i></b>';
                        }
                    }

                    else {
                    story[i] = '<b><i>' + newval3 + '</i></b>';
                    }

                }

                else if( newval2.match(/\\/) ) {
                    if(newval2.match(/\\\*/)){
                    slash_val = newval2.replace(/\\/, '');
                    story[i] = '<b>' + slash_val + '</b>';
                    }
                    else {
                    story[i] = '<b>' + newval2 + '</b>';
                    }
                }

                else {
                story[i] = '<b>' + newval2 + '</b>';
                }

            }

            else if( newval.match(/\\/) ) {
                if(newval.match(/\\\*/)){
                slash_val = newval.replace(/\\/, '');
                story[i] = '<i>' + slash_val + '</i>';
                }
                else {
                story[i] = '<i>' + newval + '</i>';
                }
            }

            else {
                story[i] = '<i>' + newval + '</i>';
            }

        }


        if( line.match(/#/) ){
            newval = line.replace(/^#/, '');
            story[i] = '<p hidden>' + newval + '</p>';
        }
        if( line.match(/##/) ){
            newval = line.replace(/^##/, '');
            story[i] = '<p hidden>' + newval + '</p>';
        }
        if( line.match(/###/) ){
            newval = line.replace(/^###/, '');
            story[i] = '<p hidden>' + newval + '</p>';
        }

    return story;

    }



}
```

I've tried re-splitting it by word in another split(" ") inside the loop then joining it again afterwards but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing markup is not a straightforward task. To name a few things:

- If an asterisk is followed by a space, it will not be the start of a formatted piece of text;
- Several parts can be formatted in one line, not only single words, but also word groups;
- Formatting may even cross over a line break.
- There might be an even number of slashes preceding an asterisk, in which case the asterisk is *not* escaped.

Here is a solution that only deals with italic, bold and italic+bold formatting, and the removal of escaping slashes. I did not deal with the hashes (`#`) as this was already quite broad for a Q&A:

```js
jQuery.fn.parseAsFountain = function() {
    var txt = this.val(),
        re = /(\s?)(\\*)(\*+)(?=(\s?))/g,
        arr,
        openAsterisks = 0,
        result = [],
        last = 0,
        start;
    while ((arr = re.exec(txt)) !== null) {
        var [all, prefix, escaped, asterisks, suffix] = arr;
        if (escaped.length % 2) { // First asterisk is escaped
            escaped += asterisks[0];
            asterisks = asterisks.substr(1);
            if (!asterisks.length) continue; // Nothing to do
        }
        var useAsterisks = 0;
        if (openAsterisks && !prefix.length) {
            useAsterisks = Math.min(openAsterisks, asterisks.length);
            // Add HTML for bold, italic or both
            result.push(
                txt.substr(last, start - useAsterisks - last),
                ['<i>','<b>','<i><b>'][useAsterisks-1],
                txt.substr(start, arr.index + escaped.length - start),
                ['</i>','</b>','</b></i>'][useAsterisks-1]);
            last = arr.index + escaped.length + useAsterisks;
            openAsterisks = 0;
        }
        if (!openAsterisks && asterisks.length > useAsterisks && !suffix.length) {
            openAsterisks = asterisks.length - useAsterisks;
            start = arr.index + prefix.length + escaped.length + asterisks.length;
        }
    }
    // Flush remaining text
    result.push(txt.substr(last));
    // Remove escaping slashes (not escaped ones!):
    result = result.join('').replace(/\\(.)/g, '$1');
    return result;
}

$('textarea').on('input', function () {
    $('pre').html($(this).parseAsFountain());
}).trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea style="width:100%" rows=5>
This is **a** test *with several* ***formats 
but*** keeping asterisks \*where* needed.
</textarea>
<h3>Rendered:</h3>
<pre>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you very much...I can build it much more from here on.. :)